# How to split ordered multiline text into array c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I want to split an ordered multiline text into array by using regex or split method.

Sample Text:

> 13. W. Bandara, S. Bailey, P. Mathiesen, J. McCarthy, C. Jones, Enterprise business process management in the public sector: The case
>       of the Department of Human Services (DHS) Australia. J. Inf. Technol.
>       Teaching Cases (2017)
> 14. W. Bandara, H. Opsahl, Developing organization-wide BPM capabilities in an SME: the approaches used, challenges and outcomes.
>       J. Inf. Technol. Teaching Cases (2017)
> 15. G. Barnett, Robotic process automation: Adding to the process transformation toolkit. White paper IT0022-0005, Ovum Consulting, 2015

Expected Output:

```
var array = new string[] 
{
  "W. Bandara, S. Bailey, P. Mathiesen, J. McCarthy, C. Jones, Enterprise business process management in the public sector: The case of the Department of Human Services (DHS) Australia. J. Inf. Technol. Teaching Cases (2017)",
  "W. Bandara, H. Opsahl, Developing organization-wide BPM capabilities in an SME: the approaches used, challenges and outcomes. J. Inf. Technol. Teaching Cases (2017)",
  "G. Barnett, Robotic process automation: Adding to the process transformation toolkit. White paper IT0022-0005, Ovum Consulting, 2015"
}
```

I've tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
var result = Regex.Split(text, @"(^\d\.)\s(.*?)$",RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

Comment: Try `var result = Regex.Split(text, @"(?m)^\d+\.\s*").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))`.

Comment: What happened to `A.M. Bassam Alkharashi, L. Jesus, R. Tregear, Establishing the Office of Business` .... ?

Comment: Which bits of the data are you interested in? Please show the expected output.

Comment: Avoid split anything more complex than 1 or 2 characters. Use a match function instead.

Comment: Is the ordered text in HTML format or plain text?

Comment: So, the splitting approach [I shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897180/how-to-split-ordered-multiline-text-into-array-c-sharp#comment102215379_57897180) should work if you only have these numbered references, nothing else before and nothing else after.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code works perfectly. Thank you !

Comment: Can you post the output of using split in your answer incase someone happens by and wants to see the _perfection_ as you are seeing it ? Coolaid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `(^\d\.)\s(.*?)$` regex contains two capturing groups and when used with `Regex.Split` in C#, it outputs all the texts captured with the capturing groups. It is not what you need. Besides, `\d` only matches 1 digit, your strings have more than 1 digit at the start of the lines.

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Split(text, @"(?m)^\d+\.\s*")
     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5Cs*%5E%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cs*&i=13.%20W.%20Bandara%2C%20S.%20Bailey%2C%20P.%20Mathiesen%2C%20J.%20McCarthy%2C%20C.%20Jones%2C%20Enterprise%20business%20process%20management%20in%20the%20public%20sector%3A%20The%20case%20of%20the%20Department%20of%20Human%20Services%20%28DHS%29%20Australia.%20J.%20Inf.%20Technol.%20Teaching%20Cases%20%282017%29%0D%0A14.%20W.%20Bandara%2C%20H.%20Opsahl%2C%20Developing%20organization-wide%20BPM%20capabilities%20in%20an%20SME%3A%20the%20approaches%20used%2C%20challenges%20and%20outcomes.%20J.%20Inf.%20Technol.%20Teaching%20Cases%20%282017%29%0D%0A15.%20G.%20Barnett%2C%20Robotic%20process%20automation%3A%20Adding%20to%20the%20process%20transformation%20toolkit.%20White%20paper%20IT0022-0005%2C%20Ovum%20Consulting%2C%202015%0D%0A)

Note the `.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))` part of code is necessary to remove the empty elements that can arise due to the first match at the start of the string.

The `(?m)^\d+\.\s*` pattern means:

- `(?m)` -  inline equivalent of `RegexOptions.Multiline` option
- `^` -  start of a line here
- `\d+` - 1+ digits (use `[0-9]` or add `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` to only match ASCII digits)
- `\.` - a dot
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Answer (score -1):

Trouble with split and your input is that you have extra line breaks
as separators so you'd have to incorporate a `(?m)\s*^` ahead of it to suck those
up. Even still, split will most of the time give you empty elements as
split is chronic about that.

Use a regular Matches() function and you're better off.

`(?m)^\S+\h+(.*)`
or
`(?m)^\S+[^\S\r\n]+(.*)`

https://regex101.com/r/uo9iwQ/1

and group 1 contains your elements.